# SQLite: How to achive RANDOM ORDER and pageintation at the same time?

Tags: sql, sqlite, random

I have a table of movies, I want to be able to query the database and get a randomized list of movies, but also I don't want it to return **all** movies available so I'm using `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`. The problem is when I'm doing something like this:

```
SELECT *  FROM Movie ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0
```

and then when querying for the next page with `LIMIT 50 OFFSET 50` the RANDOM seed changes and so it's possible for rows from the first page to be included in the second page, which is not the desired behavior.

How can I achieve a random order and preserve it through the pages? As far as I know SQLite doesn't support custom seed for it's RANDOM function.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You cant preserve the random values. You have to add another field name to your table to keep the random order

```
UPDATE movie
SET randomOrder = Random();
```

Then you can retrive the pages

```
SELECT *  
FROM Movie 
ORDER BY randomOrder 
LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0
```

Comment: Wouldn't that have a non-negligible impact on performance? If I have 10K movies in the database and need to update each row's `randomOrder` field in order to reshuffle them ?

Comment: @Curtwagner1984 Of course. But you have to store the random order *somewhere*, and if the DB needs to use it, it must be in the DB. (You could use a separate, temporary table.)