# How to implement FNV-1(a) in SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite, hash, bitwise-operators

(Moved from https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/406813/how-to-implement-fnv-1a-in-sqlite)

I'm trying to modify a SQLite query (in Android) to return its results in pseudorandom order. As in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44216165/sqlite-how-to-achive-random-order-and-pageintation-at-the-same-time), the order needs to be stable over repeated queries (e.g. due to paging, screen rotation, etc.), so I can't just use `ORDER BY RANDOM()`. Instead I want to use a hash function that depends on a couple of input values that provide stability and sufficient uniqueness. (One of these values is a unique ID column of the table, which is a set of integers fairly close together; the other value is more like an session ID, also an integer, that remains invariant within this query.)

According to [this well-researched answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/145633/8465), FNV-1 and FNV-1a are simple hash functions with few collisions and good distribution. But as simple as they are, FNV-1 and FNV-1a both involve XOR operations, as well as looping over the bytes of input.

Looping within each row of a query is pretty awkward. One could fake it by unrolling the loop, especially if only a few bytes are involved. I could make do with two bytes, combining LSBs from the two input values (`val1 & 255` and `val2 & 255`).

XOR isn't supported directly in SQLite. I understand `A ^ B` can be implemented as `(A | B) - (A & B)`. But the repetition of values, combined with the unrolling of the loop, starts to get unwieldy. Could I just use `+` (ignoring overflow) instead of XOR? I don't need very high quality randomness. The order just needs to look random to a casual observer over small-integer scales.

So I'm wondering if anyone has already implemented such a thing. Given how [widely used this hash function is](http://www.isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/fnv/#history), it seems like there would likely already be an implementation for this situation.

Here's my attempt at implementing FNV-1a:

```
SELECT ..... ORDER BY (((fnvbasis + val1 & 255) * fnvprime) + val2 & 255) * fnvprime % range;
```

I'm ignoring the fact that in FNV, the XOR operation (which I've replaced with `+`) is only supposed to affect the lowest 8 bits of the hash value. I'm also ignoring any overflow (which I hope just means the upper bits, which I don't care about, are lost).

For `fnvbasis` I'll use 16777619, and for `fnvprime` I'll use 2166136261. These are the specified values for 32 bit input, since I don't see a specified value for 16 bit input. For `range` I'll use a prime number that's greater than the expected number of rows returned by this query.

So is this a reasonable way to approximate FNV-1a in a SQLite query? Is there a better, existing implementation? I.e. will it actually produce an ordering that looks pretty random to a casual user, despite my mutilating the operations of the real FNV-1a?

Comment: Do the Android sqlite bindings include support for adding user defined functions?

Comment: Apparently not (https://stackoverflow.com/a/8283265/423105). "In order to get it to work you will need to **compile the SQLite C library** with the NDK." That's a big step up in complexity of the development process for the problem I'm trying to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by comments from rwong and GrandmasterB on [the previous attempt at this question before I moved it](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/406813/how-to-implement-fnv-1a-in-sqlite), I decided I could precompute the first iteration of FNV-1a's loop, i.e. the hash based on the unique ID column of the table. The precomputed column, `fnv1a_step1`, is set to

```
(fnvbasis ^ (ID & 0xFF)) * fnvprime
```

Because this value is precomputed on each row of the table separately, it can be supplied by the app and doesn't need to be expressed in SQLite; hence the use of `^` (XOR) above. Also, if ID is a string, we can compute an 8-bit hash value from it in Java or Kotlin as well. But we could even use

```
(fnvbasis + (RANDOM() & 0xFF)) * fnvprime
```

(back to using `+` if doing this in SQLite) because the value is only computed once, and therefore is stable even when computed from RANDOM().

The second iteration of the FNV-1a loop can be computed pretty simply in the ORDER BY clause of the query, using the current session ID, so it produces a different-but-stable ordering for each session:

```
ORDER BY (fnv1a_step1 + sessionId & 0xFF) * fnvprime % range;
```

I've implemented this in my app, and it seems to work, to my requirements. The order is stable within a session, but is different in each session.